# how to get extra form fields in form-data in post Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, multipartform-data, form-data

Key-value pairs like `name` are appended to form-data in a client-side `XMLHttpRequest` and sent with file to be uploaded.

How can I extract those values on the server side, which is using Node.js.

**Browser**:

```
formdata = new FormData();
for( var x = 0;x < files.length;x = x+1){
    formdata.append('file',files[x]);
}
formdata.append('name',name);  //name appended here to form-data
formdata.append('email',email);
formdata.append('reason',reason);
formdata.append('location',location);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "/sign_8081";
xhr.open("POST" ,url);
xhr.withCredentials = true;
```

**Node.js Server**:

```
router.post('/sign_8081', (req, res) => {
    console.log("sign 8081called"+JSON.stringify(req.body))
    console.log(req.query.name);
    console.log(req.body.name); //want name key value in Node.js code 
    let body = '';
    var rb;
    req.on('data', chunk => {
        body += chunk.toString(); // convert Buffer to string
    });
    req.on('end', () => {      
        rb = parse(body)
        console.log(rb.name);
    });
    console.log(req.file.filename)
    res.send(req.file.filename)                
});
```

Comment: I updated your post and fixed the indentation. Could you please improve the title, e.g. "How to get extra fields from form data in POST with Node.js"

Answer (score 1):

If you are using expressjs, use body-parsing middlewares such as `express.json()` or `express.urlencoded()`, then your can access form input `req.body`.

```
   var app = express()

   app.use(express.json()) // for parsing application/json
   app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })) // for parsing application/x-   www-form-urlencoded

    router.post('/sign_8081', (req, res) => {
    console.log("sign 8081called"+JSON.stringify(req.body))
    console.log(req.query.name);// do not use this
    console.log(req.body); // object of inputs
    let body = '';
    var rb;
    req.on('data', chunk => {
        body += chunk.toString(); // convert Buffer to string
    });
    req.on('end', () => {      
        rb = parse(body)
        console.log(rb.name);
    });
    console.log(req.file.filename)
    res.send(req.file.filename)                
});
```

For more on expressjs request object [expressjs docs](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body)